# Add content to Android Assistant

Tags: android, json, assistant, google-assist-api

Hello I am developing an app dealing with products and I would like to improve user experience using Android assistant.

I read Google's documentation and try first using the code below:

```
@Override
public void onProvideAssistContent(AssistContent assistContent) {
super.onProvideAssistContent(assistContent);

 String structuredJson = new JSONObject()
   .put("@type", "MusicRecording")
   .put("@id", "https://example.com/music/recording")
   .put("name", "Album Title")
   .toString();
 assistContent.setStructuredData(structuredJson);
}
```

The code is called but nothing added to normal experience of Google assistant crawling the current view.
I tried also using product schema ([schema.org](https://schema.org/)) (with @product, @brand, @review ...) because I thought the problem was the json object gave no result on a google search.
But nothing appeared with this new json.

Am I wrong when I think the problem lies on the fact that the json is inconclusive on Google search or I forgot to do semething more?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

About Google Assistant, cause it is an Assistant, so it will do more calculating before suggesting result to a user. It means with your share content, it will be data for Google Assistant learn and Google Assistant do something with it just Google know that, is not a clear concept like `if else` condition. Also, you can follow comments on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984757/how-to-provide-content-to-be-shown-on-google-now-on-tap), 
I think it will help.